# Copy Paste Dropdown object

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu, ms-word

I want to copy and paste dropdown below that original dropdown by using a VBA. It will copy & paste just below the last of the dropdown with the same lookup list every time VBA runs. I am trying it in word but can't get any clue whatsoever however seems a simple task so any help would be appreciated.(Want to avoid manual copy paste)

[image]

Comment: Please post whatever code you've tried. ActiveX dropdown? Content Control dropdown? Legacy formfield dropdown? Userform dropdown? The task you're trying to accomplish is not clear from your post.

Comment: See any of: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/27809-code-add-new-row-table.html#post87989, https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/13955-macro-add-row-table-word-form.html#post38461, & https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43603-multiple-dependent-dropdown-lists-table-add-new.html#post145675

Comment: This is simple dropdown I made by using the word options, I know excel vba but new to word